# Can I rename a wiki home page

Tags: 2007

Is it possible to rename the home page in a Sharepoint 2007 wiki?

On all other pages the option is there but on the home page the field is grayed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through code, you can, I just tested.  The only problem, is that your Wiki library is looking for a default page that has a static name (Home.aspx, i think, i'm working in french, where me it's Accueil.aspx).  The moment I changed this page to a new name, no problem appeared, except that accessing the Wiki from the Url would redirect me to the AllItems.aspx page where I see all the wiki pages.  And I can't find a way to modifiy the "Default" page of the Wiki Library... So, I would say it would not be a good idea to do, since you break the regular SharePoint behaviour !

Comment: Merci beaucoup!

Comment: Ça fait plaisir! ;)